# Verify sorting order in e-commerce website using selenium web driver java

Tags: java, selenium, sorting

Here my scenario is , verify sorting order in e-commerce website
There is an website, if i provide some value in search box and clicks on search then it will fetch some results (more than 500 pages) randomly and there prices will be `800,50000,200,100000 etc` now if i clicks on filter and sorting from Lower to highest prices then it will give results in `2,5,100,200,500,1000,20000 etc`.

Now i written script for this in selenium , i am fetching the prices only on the page 1 and putting in List name called `IntegerList1`,and arranged list in sorting order by using collections and this list named called sortedprices :- `[7300, 84999, 123000, 130000, 139000, 225000, 229000, 235850, 240000, 247900, 265000, 294900, 305000, 315000, 329000, 330000, 334900, 344900, 359000, 379000, 380000, 424900, 427850, 465000, 479000, 479000, 498000, 499000, 525000, 575000, 590000, 590000, 599000, 638900, 699000, 835000, 870000, 925000, 926000, 979900, 999000, 1050000, 1070000, 1085000, 1150000, 1395000, 1595000, 26200000]`

But when i sorted by using select class and fetching the results  and putting these all in another list called Integer list2 :-`[250, 650, 700, 750, 800, 800, 850, 1000, 1250, 1400, 1600, 1600, 1650, 1800, 2750, 4800, 7300, 7700, 8000, 8500, 10000, 11750, 15000, 18500, 22000, 22500, 22500, 24900, 25000, 29900, 30000, 30000, 30000, 31000, 32700, 33999, 34000, 34900, 34990, 35000, 35000, 35000, 35000, 37500, 38500, 39900, 40000, 40000]`

Here sortedprices list sorting the prices only on page 1 but `Integerlist2`
sorting the prcies through out the products ,Now i want to compare the sorted list and `intlist2` list .Can anybody help me getting out of it,code is as follows :

```
public void sortingPrices() throws InterruptedException{  
driver.get("URL");
List<WebElement> table = driver.findElements(By.cssSelector("[class*='data- 
price']"));
ArrayList<String> Prices1 = new ArrayList<String>();
List<Integer> IntList1 = new ArrayList<Integer>();
for(int i=0;i<table.size();i++){
Prices1.add(table.get(i).getText().replace("$", "").replace(",", ""));
}
System.out.println("prcies are "+Prices1);
System.out.println("Page 1 consists of " +Prices1.size()+ "  price 
elements");
Thread.sleep(3000);

/*converting string list Prcies1 to integer list */
for (String s: Prices1){
    IntList1.add(Integer.valueOf(s));  
}
System.out.println("Integerlist1 is "+IntList1);    

/*Array list named as sortedPrices and passing integer list into it to sort*/
ArrayList<Integer> sortedPrices = new ArrayList<Integer>(IntList1);
Collections.sort(sortedPrices);
System.out.println("Sorted list is "+sortedPrices);
/*clicking on sort dropdown and arranging in ascending order*/  
Select s = new Select(driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("[id='srp- 
sortby']")));
s.selectByValue("1");
Thread.sleep(5000);
List<WebElement>table2= driver.findElements(By.cssSelector("[class*='data- 
price']"));
List<Integer> IntList2 = new ArrayList<Integer>();
ArrayList<String> Prices2 = new ArrayList<String>();
for(int i=0;i<table2.size();i++){
    Prices2.add(table2.get(i).getText().replace("$", "").replace(",", ""));
    }
    System.out.println("price2 are "+Prices2);
/*converting string list to integer list */
for (String s1: Prices2){
    IntList2.add(Integer.valueOf(s1));  
    }
    System.out.println("Integer2 list is "+IntList2);   
}
```

Result :-

```
[RemoteTestNG] detected TestNG version 6.14.3
Starting ChromeDriver 2.40.565498 (ea082db3280dd6843ebfb08a625e3eb905c4f5ab) on port 29529
Only local connections are allowed.
Aug 08, 2018 1:12:03 PM org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake createSession
INFO: Detected dialect: OSS
Page 1 consists of 48  price elements
Integerlist1 is [7300, 84999, 139000, 225000, 235850, 925000, 123000, 424900, 1050000, 26200000, 599000, 265000, 525000, 590000, 1595000, 1395000, 638900, 334900, 1070000, 979900, 427850, 1085000, 294900, 999000, 465000, 247900, 926000, 305000, 380000, 379000, 479000, 315000, 590000, 359000, 479000, 835000, 229000, 499000, 498000, 699000, 240000, 344900, 130000, 870000, 329000, 359900, 330000, 575000]
Sorted list is [7300, 84999, 123000, 130000, 139000, 225000, 229000, 235850, 240000, 247900, 265000, 294900, 305000, 315000, 329000, 330000, 334900, 344900, 359000, 359900, 379000, 380000, 424900, 427850, 465000, 479000, 479000, 498000, 499000, 525000, 575000, 590000, 590000, 599000, 638900, 699000, 835000, 870000, 925000, 926000, 979900, 999000, 1050000, 1070000, 1085000, 1395000, 1595000, 26200000]
price2 are [250, 650, 700, 750, 800, 800, 850, 1000, 1250, 1400, 1600, 1600, 1650, 1800, 2750, 4800, 7300, 7700, 8000, 8500, 10000, 11750, 15000, 18500, 22000, 22500, 22500, 24900, 25000, 29900, 30000, 30000, 30000, 31000, 32700, 33999, 34000, 34900, 34990, 35000, 35000, 35000, 35000, 37500, 38500, 39900, 40000, 40000]
Integer2 list is [250, 650, 700, 750, 800, 800, 850, 1000, 1250, 1400, 1600, 1600, 1650, 1800, 2750, 4800, 7300, 7700, 8000, 8500, 10000, 11750, 15000, 18500, 22000, 22500, 22500, 24900, 25000, 29900, 30000, 30000, 30000, 31000, 32700, 33999, 34000, 34900, 34990, 35000, 35000, 35000, 35000, 37500, 38500, 39900, 40000, 40000]
PASSED: sorting

===============================================
    Default test
    Tests run: 1, Failures: 0, Skips: 0
===============================================


===============================================
Default suite
Total tests run: 1, Failures: 0, Skips: 0
===============================================
```

Answer (score 0):

You can first sort from web, get values, sort it with code and then compare if they equals.

```
Select s = new Select(driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("[id='srp-sortby']")));
s.selectByValue("1");    
List<WebElement> elements = driver.findElements(By.cssSelector("[class*='data-price']"));
List<String> webSortedPrices = elements.stream().map(WebElement::getText).collect(toList());
List<String> mySortedPrices = elements.stream().map(WebElement::getText).sorted(Comparator.comparingInt(Integer::valueOf)).collect(toList());
Assert.assertEquals(webSortedPrices, mySortedPrices, "Should be sorted from lower to highest price");
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer Mr. sers, i am getting error ,when i use 'collect(to List())' and what does 'toList()' means here?

Comment: You need Java 8

Comment: Anyway , i got your approach how to sort, thanks for that and i resolved it.